# How do I configure services when I bind an array of objects?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a json string attached to the VCAP_SERVICES environment variable that looks like this:

```
{
"redislabs": [
    {
        "credentials": {
            "host": "redis-1756.pcfredissb2.com",
            "ip_list": [
                "10.999.46.999"
            ],
            "password": "cz(2u",
            "port": 1756
        },
        "syslog_drain_url": null,
        "volume_mounts": [],
        "label": "redislabs",
        "provider": null,
        "plan": "simple-redis",
        "name": "sdsredis2",
        "tags": [
            "redislabs"
        ]
    },
    {
        "credentials": {
            "host": "redis-13610.pcfredis.com",
            "ip_list": [
                "10.999.46.9999"
            ],
            "password": "n-C*",
            "port": 13610
        },
        "syslog_drain_url": null,
        "volume_mounts": [],
        "label": "redislabs",
        "provider": null,
        "plan": "simple-redis",
        "name": "sdsredis",
        "tags": [
            "redislabs"
        ]
    }
]
}
```

In `ConfigureServices` in `Startup.cs`, when I run `Configuration.GetSection("redislabs").AsEnumerable()` I get something that looks like this:

[image]

I have a few options classes that looks like this:

```
public class RedisLabs
{
    public RedisLab[] redislabs { get; set; }
}

public class RedisLab
{
    public Credentials credentials { get; set; }
    public object syslog_drain_url { get; set; }
    public object[] volume_mounts { get; set; }
    public string label { get; set; }
    public object provider { get; set; }
    public string plan { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string[] tags { get; set; }
}

public class Credentials
{
    public string host { get; set; }
    public string[] ip_list { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public int port { get; set; }
}
```

My question is how the heck do I perform the binding on something like this? Is binding an array of objects even possible?

I've tried:

```
var redislabs = new List<RedisLab>();
Configuration.GetSection("redislabs").Bind(redislabs);
```

and

```
services.Configure<RedisLabs>(Configuration);
```

and a few other methods. Nothing seems to work.

Halp, plz.

Comment: Yes, default  `Configuration.GetSection` doesn't support arrays very well. It is easier to deserialize a json array manually.

Answer (score 0):

Given your json file and classes this should work (binding top level section to instance of a class that that holds the array):

```
var redisLabs = new RedisLabs();
Configuration.Bind(redisLabs);
```

This also works:

```
services.Configure<RedisLabs>(Configuration);
...
var rlOptions = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IOptions<RedisLabs>>();
var redisLabs = rlOptions.Value;
```